# Team winning and losing

Tags: probability, random-variables, combinations, conditional-probability

A team wins with a probability of $0.4$. Suppose that it plays $9$ matches.

(a) What is the probability that it will win exactly $5$ matches?

(b) What is the probability that this team will win $4$ matches before losing $5$ matches? [Hint:
one possible way is to condition on the result of the first match and build a generic iterative expression for the probability of $n$ successes before $m$ failures.]

The answer to the part (a) solved by random variables looks like as follows, is it the correct approach?

$P(A=5) = ((1-0.4)^4) \cdot 0.4^5$

What could be the way of solving the part b?

Comment: Hint for $b$:  The only way a team, $A$,  can win $4$ before losing $5$ is if the two teams are tied after the $8^{th}$ game and then $A$ loses game $9$.

Comment: You forgot to account for the number of ways in which the games are won; $WWWWWLLLL$ is not the same as $LLLLWWWWW$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P(Win) = 0.4 P(Lose) = 1-0.4 = 0.6
Assuming that only two events win and lose is possible.
Number of ways of choosing 5 matches out of 9 matchers = $\binom{9}{5}$.
Probability that it will win exactly 5 mtaches = $\binom{9}{5}$ $0.4^5$ $0.6^4$.
Probability that this team will win 4 matches before losing 5 matches = $0.4^4$  $0.6^5$.
Since there is only one way of winning 4 matches before losing 5 matches.